# Django's views select template under different conditions

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I need to create Django's view that it must be able to select one template between multiple templates for some cases.
In other words, I'm trying to find the best way for a selective and interactive choice template in views between different templates.

I know that I can do this:

```
def view(request, case):
    if case == 'case1':
        return render(request, 'case1.html')
    if case == 'case2':
        return render(request, 'case2.html')
    if case == 'case3':
        return render(request, 'case3.html')
```

Does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check how it's been done in Django's flatpages app.

See [flatpages' models](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/flatpages/models.py#L16-L17) and [flatpages' views](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/flatpages/views.py)

In short: add a CharField, eg. `template_path`, to your model where you enter the template path. Render the template specified in your `MyModel.template_path` in the page view.

Comment: I won't use any cms in django.I'm going to write post system in my website and I use several templates in my project.Thank you for your answer.Please explain by example for me?